# Facebook Session Closed

Tags: ios, facebook, session, facebook-login

I'm implementing the Facebook Login in my iOS app. I think it is well implemented, however I have a problem. I run the login at the settings of the application. When I leave the app and then when I come back, if I want to use a Facebook action (i.e. share photos) I'm not able to do that because the session is closed. When I go to the settings menu where I've the login button, the session reopen without perform the login again (just direct me to the view where is the login button and the session is opened again).

So, I need the active session without the user having (always) to go to the settings menu. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: how you are doing because it never asked me until my access token is valid

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand. Can you repeat? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem :

had to make

> @property (strong, nonatomic) FBSession *session;

in AppDelegate

in

> - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
>     [FBAppEvents activateApp];
>     [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:self.session]; }

in

> - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application { [self.session close]; }

in

> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
>             openURL:(NSURL *)url   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
>          annotation:(id)annotation {
>     return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
>                   sourceApplication:sourceApplication
>                         withSession:self.session]; }

in your settings class

> if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
>           {
>
> ```
>         [FBSession setActiveSession:appDelegate.session];
>         [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
> ```
>
> NSDictionary *user, NSError *error)
>                {
>                    [self registerationWithFBRequestConnection:connection andFBGraphUser:user andNSError:error];
>                }];
>
> ```
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
>         NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email", nil];
>         appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
>         [FBSession setActiveSession:appDelegate.session];
>
>         [appDelegate.session openWithBehavior:(FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView)
> ```
>
> completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError
>   *error)
>                {
>                    [self sessionStateChangedWithFBSession:session andFBSessionState:status andNSError:error];
>                }];
>
> ```
>     }
> ```
>
> - (void)sessionStateChangedWithFBSession:(FBSession*)session andFBSessionState:(FBSessionState)status andNSError:(NSError*) error {
>     switch (status)
>     {
>         case FBSessionStateOpen:
>         { [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
>     NSDictionary *user, NSError *error)
>              {
>
>   ```
>            [self registerationWithFBRequestConnection:connection andFBGraphUser:user andNSError:error];
>        }]; }
>       break;
>   case FBSessionStateClosed:
>
>       break;
>   case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
>
>       break;
>   default:
>       break;
>   ```
>
>   } }
>     in your in `registerationWithFBRequestConnection:` methods you should handle it.. in Settings get all information about user.